# pass selected row elements from angular datatable to spring boot

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I need to implement a secure way to store data of selected row id in material datatable in angular 7 in memory and pass them to spring boot application as session and not in RequestBody. Using localstorage or sessionstorage in angular 
is it possible or isn't it secure? Is there any other way to solve this? I don't necessarily need to post sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Your service should be like below.

```
@Injectable()
export class YourService {

  public selectedData: any;

  constructor() {        
  }

  setSelectedData(selectedData) {
    this.selectedData= selectedData;
  }
  getSelectedData() {
    return this.selectedData;
  }

}
```

From your component to set value like below.

```
this._YourService.setSelectedData(selectedData);
```

From your component to get value like below.

```
let selected = this._YourService.getSelectedData();
```

service must be added into the controller...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a common service with get and set method. So that you can set the value on the row selected. You can retrieve it whenever you want.

Comment: A service in angular right? What if you have to handle a large amount of data?

Comment: You can store any amount of data. But it might reduce application performance. Try to store reference, with the reference you can repopulate the data.  localstorage or sessionstorage max storage size 5MB to 10MB max.

Comment: can you provide an example or tutorial link about storing reference or about creating a service with setters and getters ? It would be very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can store the data by converting it in to a **base64** by using this method and then send that base64 data into request.

```
let data = btoa("password");
```

If you store data in to localStorage or sessionStorage but then you can not access localStorage or SessionStorage from backend side so you need to pass the data by request.

Comment: Yes but someone could change the request and call the service with random values right?

Comment: ohh okay, For that you can also send data by using a Socket.IO. Socket.IO is mainly designed for realtime and bi-directional connections between client and server and in some applications there is no need to keep permanent connections. On the other hand Ajax async connections should pass the HTTP connection setup phase and send header data and all cookies with every request.